# More than 8 peers in Multipeer framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

Am I correct in assuming that no more than 8 peers can be connected and chatting in the same "room" with Apple's example code?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html

This mentions the 8 maximum peer per session limit:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/MultipeerConnectivityFramework.pdf

If so, how can the code be modified to allow more than 8 peers in the same chat room?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: The multipeer frameword works over wifi, ad-hoc wifi, and bluetooth technologies.  I've never used it, but it's possible that it searches all of those options and finds a viable one and uses it.  In this case it would have to limit everything based on the lowest limit of all those technologies.  In your case it would be bluetooth, which has a 8 peer limit (including self).  Wifi should have a much larger limit, but I'm not sure how Apple takes that into account.

Comment: I'm looking at the same problem @codeman - I have to extend my app to support 32 peers.  I just tested the current app (single MCsession) with 9 peers and it works fine in a single session.  Stumped.  I wanted to see how the framework would fail so I could factor that into the design.

Comment: @codeman hello, did you find a way to get above the 8 peer limit? If so can you please post some info on it or a github repo if possible

Answer (score 2):

8 is the practical maximum. We've tried to get more than 8 but can never do so reliably and we've spent a fair amount of time trying to make this happen as our app is a presentation app that allows the host to flip pages that automatically flip on the participant's devices.